# [Meta] Upvotes and view count

Tags: meta, site-logistics

I just noticed a few posts with +200 views and single digit upvotes.
How does that happen? They are good questions.
More importantly why and does this format really work?
Non registered users I assume, which is fine, its just an odd stat comparison.

I am posting this here as a wiki for honest discussion.  PJ and I exchanged a couple comments recently over the "active community" comments made earlier last week.

I think this is a cool format with potential to really entertain and inform.
But why is the site so slow, where is the new traffic coming from?

Thoughts?

We can delete this post in the future if necessary, BTW. We can delete it right now!

Comment: +1 I have noticed the same phenomenon. Lots of views, few votes. Perhaps we just need to get more traffic on the site. Spread the word a bit more ..? I heard about it from a programmer friend who said that stackexchange is *the* place for programmers. It would be nice if it were  an essential resource for homebrewers too.

Answer (score 4):

I believe if everyone follows some sort of voting etiquette (as discussed [here](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/435/meta-voting-etiquette)) we'd have more votes. But, sometimes we just don't. I would love to see more people voting, both up and down. I've never felt [peer pressure](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/badges/36/peer-pressure) to delete an answer like I have on SO. And only 3 of us have the "[civic duty](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/badges/32/civic-duty)" badge.

It's funny, I would generally never attempt to compare this site to SO, but Kyle makes a great point in that even on a site where some people have 30k+ rep, non-discussion questions tend to get less than 10 votes.

Comment: Excellent thoughts.  Tell me this, do you also see on SO that as soon as there is an accepted answer people stop answering and/or voting?  Almost as if the question is some how closed.  This comment is open to Kyle as well.

Comment: Ya for sure. I've definitely refrained from accepting an answer right away, both here and on SO, to make sure people would still check it out. I've also changed my accepted answer to a better one before, both on here and SO. But, that's me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is unique to brewadvice.com. The most popular question I have asked on www.stackoverflow.com has almost 9k views and only 7 upvotes. The accepted answer (which is correct) has 6 upvotes. The number of votes is fairly irrelevant if it's a good question with a correct answer that helps the people who view it.

Comment: 9K and 7 upvotes, wow that is an interesting phenomenon.  I would think you give people something to do other than just READ the site and they'd take advantage of it and vote. I mean you read it and that's great, but with the option to vote you can at least feel like you are part of the knowledge base process.  Fascinating to me from a behavioral standpoint.

Comment: I think a lot of people don't realize they can change their votes.. Like, here's a -1 vote, pending a change. Then turn it into a +1. Or a 0. Whatever... But ya, I'd like to see more votes on here. We have 347 questions on this site. Two of them have 10 votes. One has 9. Three have 8. The rest are lower.